# Angular routing doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Disclaimer: Yes, I have read many other posts, but haven't been able to find the solution.

So, I have set up a basic Angular app:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="#/">Home</a>
            <a href="#/aboutme">About me</a>
            <a href="#/projects">Projects</a>
            <a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);    
myApp.config(
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
        }).
        when('/aboutme', {
            templateUrl: 'views/aboutme.html'
        }).
        when('/projects', {
            templateUrl: 'views/projects.html'
        }).
        when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
);
```

When I start the server (`npm install http-server` followed by `http-server -o`) and run the app, I can see the `main.html` content and the navigation links. The URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/`. When I click e.g. **Projects**, the URL becomes `http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/#%2Fprojects`, but the page content is still the same (navigation links + `main.html`'s content).

I have also tried modifying **app.js** like this:

```
...
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
    ...
}]);
```

...but the outcome is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you a error message?

Comment: In your index.html put in your head `<base href="/">` to avoid the /#! and get the direct url

Comment: have you tried removing the `/` as in `<a href="#projects">Projects</a>`

Comment: @Leaf no, no error message

Comment: @ocespedes I added that, but the problem still remains

Comment: @Jax yeah, I've tried that too, but nothing changes

Comment: Well do not use href directly, instead use `ng-href` directive

Comment: @ocespedes nope... still the same... it doesn't load any of the views (other than mail.html)

Comment: did you do something like `<a ng-href="projects">Projects</a>`?

Comment: @ocespedes if I do that, the link will send me to http://127.0.0.1:8080/projects, which doesn't exist

Comment: it seems to working file i create a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/6UN0H4WVVM90Xzg1zpxc?p=preview

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I swapped my <script src="js/angular.js"> with your version and it worked. Thanks :). If you want to write a regular answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to be working fine. And as mention in the comments need to check the angular version. i create a sample [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6UN0H4WVVM90Xzg1zpxc?p=preview)

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.10" data-semver="1.5.10" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-router@1.2.0-rc1" data-semver="1.2.0-rc1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.js"></script>
```